# Local Installation: install.php offered to download instead of running

Tags: installation

I am running ubuntu 10.04 desktop, php5.3, and wordpress 3.2.1.  I copied the wordpress directory to `/var/www/sitename/blog`.  I have set up mysql, and edited wp-config.php appropriately.  But when I navigate to `http://localhost/sitename/blog/wp-admin/install.php`, I am only offered to save or download the install.php file.  I can run php scripts in any `/var/www/` directory, including `/var/www/site/blog/wp-admin/`.

I have been searching for a solution, but have not found anything relevant.  What do I need to do in order to make the installation run?

Answer (score 1):

Two things I would try:

1. Create a test.php file and only put `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it.
2. If that doesn't work I would create an .htaccess file and put:

   AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html

   AddHandler x-httpd-php .php .htm .html

When you are asked to download a php file, it usually means that php isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

This was driving me a little bit nuts as well, so I'm commenting here to populate the google with an answer to it.

Rename install.php to something else.  I believe this to be a caching issue from trying to run install.php before php was properly installed, but I'm not sure.

In any case, renaming install.php to iinstall.php worked fine for me.

(So did moving wordpress to a different directory)